# How to generate a histogram with many values in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a txt file called values.txt that has 29172 numbers in a single column. I wish to make a histogram from this by entering the commands below:

```
val = read.table("values.txt", col.name = c("col1"))
hist(val$col1)
```

But this gives a weird histogram like the below. What's the matter with the code?
[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an error in your code. Since the plot has a very wide range, I assume that you have an outlier in your values (around -15000). Try sorting the values in `col1` and see if there is such an extreme value

Answer (score 1):

Check what's the actual range of your values via

```
summary(val$col1)
```

If the histogram shows a seemingly empty range (as in your shown example which goes to -15000) then typically you have *outliers* in that range. Hence, I would assume that summary tells you there is a minimum value somewhere in -15000 as the x-axis captures by default the full range of values.

You can try to specify `xlim=c(-500,1000)` as an option into `hist()` to "zoom in". Moreover, you may want to specify `breaks = 500` to configure the bin size afterwards.

Alternatively I suggest working with [ggplot's geom_histogram](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(val) + geom_histogram(vars(col1))
```